# KendoUI ANgular 5 use .find () on DataType Observable<any>

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, find, observable

in a Kendo UI Angular (5) Grid I need a Cell-Template to resolve the Foreign-Key, where the corresponding datasource is load async ():

.html:

```
<kendo-grid-column field="FKID" title="Foreign">
  <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem="dataItem">                
    {{getstringval(dataItem.FKID)?.Name}}
  </ng-template>
```

.ts

```
public getstringval(iKey: number): any{    
  return this.viewData.find(x =>x.Id===iKey);

  //this.viewData is of type Observable<any>

}
```

But I get the following Error-Message:

```
this.viewData.find is not a function
```

Problem, is obviously that viewData is of Type. `Observable<any>`

So the question ist how to use the ".find()" function on an variable of type `Observable<any>`???

Greetings and THX in advance

Comment: Is `this.viewData` initialized somewhere?

Comment: Yep at the top of the componentr
viewData : Observable<any>

Comment: And what is its value?

Comment: Right hint: THANKS:
the desired vaules  are saved in 
this.viewData["destination"].data

Comment: It seems that the "destination"-Member is used for saving data in async loaded observables. I have to check this. But til now it works.
THANKS again